# Problem saving svg with inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg, save

I just started playing with inkscape on Ubuntu, and I'm facing a problem when I'm saving svg files. When I save my file and close it, the miniature in Nautilus doesn't correspond to the file itself. Some items are missing, and I can't figure out why.

When I open the files with inkscape, there is no problem,everything is there. But if I open the file with anything else (Gimp, for example), the items that were not present on the miniature are not there.

I tried saving with all different svg options that inkscape offers, and I can't figure out a solution.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks!

Here's an example of a problematic file: http://www.filedropper.com/asaisir2

Comment: I should add that another problem I have is that the text does appear, but with a different font then the one I used, which is a downloaded font. Any solutions for this are welcome too :)

Comment: You should make a sample SVG file available. Try to create a minimal example that exhibits missing elements and a different font.

Comment: *But if I open the file with anything else (Gimp, for example), the items that were not present on the miniature are not there.* – Either the *but* or the second *not* do not belong here.

Comment: Excuse me for not being an English native ;)

Comment: @Annobis: Note that you can [edit] your answer to correct this. Also this has probably little do with your English skills, but rather with the text structure. You switch back and forth between other applications and Inkscape and I am honestly not certain what you see in GIMP. (Finally note that you can have me alerted about your comment by using an @-construction as I did in the beginning of this comment.)

Comment: Please upload your file here and not at some image hoster, where we have to register and input fancy captchas to download them, then open them locally, delete them, maybe redownload later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVGs can contain several types of objects such as paths (Bézier polygons), rectangles, circles, or text. Moreover, Inkscape supports extensions to these objects for its own purposes that are not part of the SVG standard (saving as plain SVG instead of Inkscape SVG should get rid of the latter).

Now, some SVG renderers ignore certain types of objects such as text, or they render them differently (e.g., due to a lacking font). This is probably what happened with your thumbnail view. For example, applying *Object to Path* on your text may cause it to be rendered in your thumbnail view. However, you lose the advantages of having a text object, such as hinting or the ability to edit the text.

So, there was no problem with saving your SVG, but with rendering it. If your target application renders your SVG as intended, you have no reason to worry.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I should've tought about this! Thank you :)

Comment: Selecting the text in Inkscape and using "Path -> Object to Path" worked for me, thx for the solution